How to level block wall So i can install baseboards
What plastering/parging/pre mixed concrete patching compound can i use over a small section of this interior block wall so that it is level with the rest? The thickness required is 3/8". I don't care about finish since I want to install baseboards over this. It is a small area (6" tall by 6" wide, about 4 such sections, located near bottom of wall).
See pics
Needs:

Needs to be able to hold a screw (not crumble easily) for baseboards
Must be easy to work with
Durable - don't want to have to redo this in 5 years
Pre mixed compound would be a strong nice-to-have

Sakret parging mix seems recommended online but I couldnt' find info to determine fit for my need.
I see Sakrete Fast patch available in my local store and it seems easier to use (it's pre mixed and sets quickly). I know it's a concrete patch repair product, but given the small area and my use case being a hidden away wall with a need to not crumble with screws, I'm wondering if it can be used for this purpose.


I'd be tempted to find some PVC boards of the right thickness to match the drywall above and attach them every foot or so. Then attach the trim to that. Easier to install, and easier to remove if you don't like it.
